# Как в laravel 5 сгенерировать URL с параметрами?

Tags: laravel

```
URL::to('/manage/users',['param' => 'value'])
```

Эта конструкция возвращает

> site.dev/manage/users/value

, а мне нужно

```
site.dev/manage/users?param=value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 URL::action('UsersController@AllUsers',['param' => 'value'])
```

Через URL::action получится как надо